# Page-break in iframe on Chrome not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a iframe inside my application and if I add page break on some `div`, it is ignored on Chrome (on Safari it works as expected).

I just have this print css that controls page-breaks:

`page-break-before: always; 
page-break-inside: avoid;`

Also if I open this iframe as a separate page, page breaks also work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

the parent and the element onto which you want to control page-breaking must be declared as:

```
position: relative;
```

This is true for:

```
page-break-before
page-break-after
page-break-inside
```

but controlling `page-break-inside` it'll not work on Safari (tested on 5.1.7 version)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this same issue. In my scenario, I was using a hidden iframe to seamlessly load the print-friendly content and then trigger the print dialog. By specifying a width of 0px (or even 1px) on the iframe element, Chrome would effectively ignore my print CSS.

By specifying only a height of 0px and leaving the width unset, Chrome began honoring the print styles.